# How to deduce whether $\sqrt{3}i \in \mathbb Q (u)$ or not, where u is a root of $x^3-2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

How can one deduce whether $\sqrt{3}i \in \mathbb Q (u)$  or not, where u is a root of $x^3-2$ ?

$\mathbb Q (u) = \{c_0 +c_1u+c_2u^2 | c_i \in \mathbb Q\}$

Is it a trivial computation, or does this perhaps rely on heavy theory?

Edit: Observed that it is trivial if the root of $x^3-2$ is the real root. Would still like to know what the case is for the other roots.

Comment: 3 answers posted within 20 seconds ^^

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: I also shocked :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all notice that $x^3-2$ is irreducable over $\mathbb Q$,

so $|\mathbb Q(u):\mathbb Q|=3$ and $m=\sqrt3i$ is a root of $x^2+3$ so $|\mathbb Q(m):\mathbb Q|=2$

Since $2$ does not divides $3$, $\mathbb Q(m)$ can not be subfield of $\mathbb Q(u)\implies m\notin \mathbb Q(u) $

Answer (score 6):

If one is allowed to use some machinery, one can use a degree argument. The field $\mathbb{Q}(u)$ has degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}i)$ has degree $2$, and $2$ does not divide $3$.

Answer (score 2):

You want to define $\sqrt{3} i$ in a condition that can be expressed internally to $\mathbb{Q}[u]$ namely: "is there an element in $\mathbb{Q}[u]$ that squares to $-3$?"

$$(c_0+c_1u+c_2u^2)^2=-3$$
$$c_0^2+2c_0c_1u+(2c_0c_2+{c_1}^2)u^2+4c_1c_2+2{c_2}^2u=-3$$

The only way of representing $-3$ is for the $\mathbb{Q}$ term coefficient to be $-3$ and the others to be zero:

$${c_0}^2+4c_1c_2=-3$$
$$2{c_2}^2+2c_0c_1=0$$
$${c_1}^2+2c_0c_2=0$$

And some mildly annoying algebra can show that this set of equations has no rational solution.

It's also worth noting that proving it in the real case proves it in the general case, so you don't need to consider the other roots separately. The field structure here "can't detect" the difference between different cube roots of $2$, since they all have the same algebraic relations to each other and the rationals.

Comment: Is it possible for you to be even more precise about why it holds to prove it in the real case?

Comment: @Improve the equations are the same regardless of which root $u$ of $X^3-2$ one has chosen, they don't see the root, the only thing that matters is the relation $u^3=2$.

Comment: @Olivier Bégassat But, the reason I said that the case with the real u is trivial, is because $\mathbb Q (u)$ is a field with only real values, and thus could not possibly contain $\sqrt{3}i$. Does that extend?

Comment: @Improve yes, with no extra effort. It's not a separate identical looking argument for the other roots or anything, you already have the entire result by that very statement you gave. Algebra can't tell the difference between the roots: it has no sense of 'where' they are, only the algebraic relationships they satisfy. So if it's not possible for one of them it can't be possible for any of them, because that would imply that algebraic relationships could somehow make a distinction between two quantities that satisfy all the same algebraic relationships, which is a contradictory statement.

Comment: Ok. So $2^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{\frac{2\pi i }{3}}$ is imaginary and is therefore not in $\mathbb Q (2^{\frac{1}{3}})$. Therefore $2^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{\frac{2\pi i }{3}}$ is not in $\mathbb Q(u)$ for  any u, where $u^3=2$ ?